# Compute the area "inside" a set of polygons

Tags: area, polygons

I have a set of disjoint polygons $\cal P$.

I want to compute the area of:

$$\left\{ (x, y), \qquad \exists P_w \in {\cal P}, \exists (x_w, y) \in P_w, x_w \ge x \qquad \text{and} \qquad \exists P_h \in {\cal P}, \exists (x, y_h) \in P_h, y_h \ge y \right\}$$

That is, a point is in this set if and only if there exists a point belonging to a polygon with the same $y$-coordinate and a greater $x$-coordinate and there exists a point belonging to a polygon with the same $x$-coordinate and a greater $y$-coordinate.

This set should be included inside the convex hull, but might be different.

Here is an example with three (black) U-shaped polygons. I would like to compute the area in red:
[image]

Is there a known way to compute this?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: What is the motivation for looking into this problem?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork not much, it's not my field, I haven't found a way to compute it yet and don't want to spend days working on this if there is already a known way to compute this, or if it is obvious for someone more familiar with the field

Comment: @OliverHouse asses the quality of partial solutions of packing algorithms

Comment: @JeanMarie you're right, I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S$ be the union of polygons $P_w$.

The set $T$ you are describing can be seen as $V \cap H$  (what I call here "shadow sets", this terminology being non-official)

- a vertical shadow set $V$ when the "sun" is placed at infinity above $S$,
- a horizontal shadow set $H$ when the "sun" is placed at infinity on the right of $S$.

It will be good to limit the extension of these shadow sets to the ordinate of the lowest point of $S$ for $V$ and to the abscissa of the leftmost point of $S$ for $H$.

Now, you don't say exactly how your shapes are given.

- If they are pixels on a digital grid, the computation of its area can be obtained by

$area(V \cap H) \ = \ area (V)+area(H)-area(V \cup H)$

- Otherwise, if your polygons are given by the coordinates of their vertices, you could consider for example the computation of area(V) by first constructing the "epigraph" (upper limit of the constitutive upper sides of polygons $P_k$), and then take the integral of the function having this epigraph.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a reference talking about this shadow sets and how to compute them (efficiently)? I tried to google a bit but haven't found anything related

Comment: That does not seem to match the answer in the example in the question.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker It does ! Besides, I have added considerations about the computation of area.

Comment: Polygons are given as list of points. Then I guess I can compute the upper limit by gathering and sorting all $x$-coordinates. For each pair of consecutive values, I compute the max by looping through all edges of the polygons. And in the same way get the right limit

Comment: Indeed, that's the way it could be done in an algorithmical way (I have attempted to write it just now)

Comment: I just added a graphic. One more thing; these "shadow sets" could be obtained in image processing by mathematical morphology operators called "conditional dilation"